# display a specific page only the 1st time user visite our site

Tags: php, cookies, drupal, drupal-7, session-cookies

I am working on darskite project in case of crisis. For this project we want to prepare a specific case.

We need to inform the user visiting our website of the crisis (eg : our factory has an electrical failure). We want to show him this specific page of information only during the first time he comes in our website. For the next visits, he must visit our classical homepage.

How can we target and identify a user to redirect him only once to the alert message (when he first logs in)? Are there any solutions like those for retargeting Google or Facebook via cookies? If Yes, what kind of cookie ?

Our website is powered by Drupal 7. Can Drupal handle this case?

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: when user came first to your site, set cookies using php, than if user visit second time search if cookies exist redirect to your desire website.

Comment: Reverse logic,  show it for all and add a button "ok" , user click on it and its save information into cookie (or database IP + user_agent if you need stats etc..)

Answer (score 1):

From the drupal docs:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_cookie_save/7.x

What you can do is: You first check if a cookie has been set. If not, then you set it. The next time the user visits your site, he/she will have a cookie so the logic gate will be passed.

Here's an example that you can use in your header file in drupal:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['some_descriptive_cookie_name'])) {
     user_cookie_save('some_descriptive_cookie_name');
     drupal_goto('temp/page/here', [], 307);
}
```

`drupal_goto` is documented here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. You can do it using the JavaScript's `localstorage`
2. You can do it using PHP's `$_SESSION[' ']`

Both will follow the same mechanism, when user loads the webpage for the first time, set a variable as `true`. Now for the next visits check this variable, if it is set to true, don't load the first page and redirect it to your classical page.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal can handle almost everything.

What I would do is to create a boolean private field in the users profile to store if the user already saw that particular page.

Following this approach you can also make reports about how many users have seen that page, or know if a particular user saw that page. Using fields gives you a lot of power in Drupal.

How can you store this value when the user sees the page? Check the rules module and don't forget to active the rules UI so you can configure this action triggered by the mentioned condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_user_login`.

```
function MODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  // The user has never logged in before.
  if ($account->access == 0) {
    // Redirect user when first login.
    $_GET['destination'] = 'redirect_url';
  }
}
```